# How to define a CKRecord class

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, cloudkit, ckrecord

I thought it might be a good idea to define my basic data object containing info as a CKRecord, as I will obviously be using CloudKit.  However, I don't know how to make a class of CKRecord.  In particular, I don't know how to define its "recordType".

My specific question: why does the line "self.recordType = "myRecordType" give rise to error "Can not assign to recordType in self"?  Each of this CKRecord class will be of the same type, so how do I assign it a recordType?

My secondary question if you have observations: Do you see any other issues with using a object of this class in CloudKit (reading and writing) directly in the queries, etc? Please let me know if you have seen similar sample code somewhere. Thx

```
class testCKRecordClass: CKRecord {

    override init!(recordType: String!) {
        self.recordType = "myRecordType"
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var title: NSString {
        get {
            return self.objectForKey("title") as NSString
        }
        set {
            self.setObject(newValue, forKey: "title")
        }
    }

    var location: CLLocation? {
        get {
            return self.objectForKey("location") as? CLLocation
        }
        set {
            self.setObject(newValue, forKey: "location")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A CKRecord is something that will be returned by the CloudKit methods. That can not be parsed to your testCKRecordClass (easilly). So you could only use this for creating a CKRecord for writing it to CloudKit.

A recordType can only be initiated by the constructor of CKRecord. Maybe it could work if you call super.init(recordType)

It looks like you only want a way to use CloudKit as easy as possible. If so, then I can advice you too have a look at https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao It's a CloudKit convenience library that will use reflection to parse from and to a CKRecord.

Comment: Thanks.  You do create CKRecords before you save them to CloudKit, so I just want to use a CKRecord class as my object model for my data chunks.  Maybe the github project link does something similar.  I have done other work with CloudKit and am comfortable doing it natively if possible.

Comment: The github project uses a baseclass that contains fields for the metadata properties that can be returned by CloudKit. Before saving an object to CloudKit it will create a CKRecord and use reflection on that object to add all the fields. When reading from CloudKit it will do the same trick but then the other way around. This way you only have to add a reference to that baseballs and don't need additional coding.

Comment: I will definitely play around with it.  Thank you